# Passing set to method_missing (mixpanel)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, mixpanel

I'm currently settings up mixpanel for our service and it's all working great, however I want to pass mixpanel as a method_missing if in development/test environment.

I have this in my application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :initialize_mixpanel

def initialize_mixpanel
  if ENV.has_key?('MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN')
    @tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new('MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN', request.env)
  else
    @tracker = DummyMixpanel.new
  end
end
```

and this in my mixpanel.rb:

```
unless ENV.has_key?('MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN')
  class DummyMixpanel
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      true
    end
  end
end
```

this works for a normal tracker like @tracker.track(.. but when trying to pass .set method to it, it returns **NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for true:TrueClass** for example using this code:

```
@tracker.people.set(current_subscriber.id, {
  '$name'             => current_subscriber.name,
  '$email'            => current_subscriber.email,
  '$hometown'       => current_subscriber.hometown,
  '$birth_year'            => current_subscriber.birth_year,
}, ip=current_subscriber.ip);
```

How would I best handle this?

All the best,

Comment: Your `DummyMixpanel` has no method `people`. It returns `true` instead (see `method_missing`). `true` has no method `set`, so it raises an error when you try to call `@tracker.people.set(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning `self` in `#method_missing` like:

```
class DummyMixpanel
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    self
  end
end
```

More info: http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/